How to scroll a screen that has a recyclerview without using nestedscrollview?
I have a view with a RecyclerView and other elements placed in a NestedScrollView. My problem is that when there are too many items in the RecyclerView, the interface freezes for a few seconds.
I have already figured out that this is due to the use of NestedScrollView. If you remove it, then everything is fine.
But I need to scroll the entire screen. How can this be done without NestedScrollView?
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Other elements -->

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerTask"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_task" />
        </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

This is init RecyclerView:
binding.recyclerTask.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            itemAnimator = null
            adapter = adapterTasks
        }


Try to give recyclerTask.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); in java or
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" in xml file.

@DroidFlutter It didn't help. I also tried to specify it and used ScrollView instead of NestedScrollView. The list began to display normally quickly without freezing. But not all items are displayed in RecyclerView, but only those that fit on the screen at once.

Try with added code below.

RecyclerView needs to have fixed size and ability to scroll itself to leverage view recycling. Setting it to "wrap_content" can be misleading as it is intended only for small lists as it essentially removes its main optimization (view recycling). As weird as it is your best bet might be incorporate your "other elements" as recyclerview items to drop entire nested/linear layout structure.

@Pawel So. How can I do this?

I'd suggesting using ConcatAdapter - create new adapter that has size of and inflates each of your header elements as "items". Then append it with your current adapter and your layout becomes only recyclerview with height that matches parent.

Use
CoordinatorLayout along with AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout
and your Other elements in CollapsingToolbarLayout
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

         <!-- Other elements -->

</com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerTask"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


Thanks! The solution is not ideal (when scrolling sharply, it first stops in front of the list, it turns out that the AppBar hides and then flips easily), but this solution is the only one that somehow helped. It is also worth noting that RecyclerView should have the following: android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"

There is another problem, when I try to do a Drag&Drop, the list starts behaving erratically. Sometimes it does not scroll through when dragging an element, then it abruptly drops the element
